# My college manages my Google account, can they view my browsing history if I use a personal device on a home network while logged in?

Tags: network, privacy, web-browser, appsec, account-security

I have found multiple sources telling me otherwise, but most are outdated by a year or two. If I am logged into my G-suite managed account on google, and search something up on a home network and personal device, can my school still see my browsing history? If it makes a difference, in Web and App Activity the option for recording history is off for the account and is disabled by my G-suite organization.

From what I have read, the only way for a G-suite administrator can view your browsing history is if your Web Activity option is enabled and they reset your password to log into your account and view it there, but not any other way (especially not without you noticing). Does this still hold true? Or have things changed recently with the new normal of online learning. If any G-Suite administrators could shed some insight it would be extremely helpful, thanks!

Comment: A good general rule is to assume that if you're logged into something, you're communicating with it.  If you have a separate personal device, don't be logged into your externally-managed account on it while doing any sensitive work (however you define sensitive):  You can transfer any data manually later on.

Comment: Chrome Profiles are made for situations like this